# Paint QPixmap into a circle?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qpixmap

I can paint a `QPixmap` just fine:

```
QPainter painter;
painter.drawPixmap(x, y, w, h, my_pixmap);
```

And I can also draw a circle with:

```
painter.drawArc(x, y, w, h, a, alen);
```

Now I want to combine these two; my pixmap might not always be a circle (=transparent corners) so I can't just paint the whole pixmap on the screen.
This means that I need to paint only the center of my pixmap.

Here's an image to make it more clear:

[image: camel]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this by setting a clip path on the painter.  Something like this should work:

```
QPainterPath path;
path.addEllipse(x, y, w, h);
painter.setClipPath(path);
painter.drawPixmap(x, y, w, h, my_pixmap);
```